# Modifying the Nutch crawler to parse the page and get certain data from the pages crawled

Tags: java, web-crawler, nutch

I want to crawl several sites and collect data based on the language i.e. "Java" etc. I am new to Nutch crawler. I just finished setup of Nutch 2.3 with HBase. How to customize the crawling so that when each page is parsed I can get the links within that page and extract some data from it. Such as date, topic etc.

Thank you.

Comment: Follow the http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/#Tutorials

Comment: also you can use http://jsoup.org/ to crawl web pages.

Comment: Nutch parses the data from the webpage and store it into the hbase. You can get the outlinks and its parsed content. You should check the webtable in hbase. It must contain the necessary information for you. Make sure to check after running the parse command.

Comment: @Computergodzilla I do find data in Hbase's webpage table,  but its some weird columns which I don't want, I want specific information from the page. And if you could add something more for the AJAX based website support in Nutch, it would be nice.

Comment: Would this query would help. scan '<your_crawl_id>_webpage',{COLUMNS => ['p:ol']}. This will give you all the outlinks. Sorry dont know about AJAX based support.

Answer (score 1):

Probably late, but for anyone facing same issue. This is solved by providing your own ParseFilter plugin.

You can read about plugins at [this documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/AboutPlugins)

Basically you implement method parse which has DocumentFragment object as argument. From DocumentFragment you can then parse whatever info you need using xPath. Parsed data can be saved inside WebPage metadata.

After you implement plugin you just have to include it into source, use in nutch-site.xml, build and you are good to go.